# Hide one View depending on Visibility of another

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm experimenting a little bit with `RxJava`, and I have stuck in a what sounds to be a simple task.
Let's say we have two `Views`, `View1` and `View2`.
Right now I'm trying to accomplish that, when `View1` is visible, the `View2` needs to be gone.

P.S. I'm searching for `RxJava` solution.

## Edit 2

As I mentioned in comment, I was trying to use `RxView.visibility()`.
So therefor I did not publish any code, because none of it worked and it's mostly one line.
As for the down voters, at least try to mention what you don't like about the question, so I could improve it.

Comment: `if(view1.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
        view2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else {
        view2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }`

Comment: As sad, I'm searching for RxJava solution, the reason is keyboard buttons, clicks on another views where I hide `view1`...
I have written code, but it isnt working at all, mostly I was trying with `RxView.visibility()`

Comment: Do you find the solution? I see you use RxBinding

Comment: No I did not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RxView.layoutChangeEvents(view1)
   .subscribe(ignore -> {
      if (view1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
         view2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      } else {
         view2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
   }, throwable -> new Exception(throwable));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do in your experiments, I think in your case you don't need RxJava, it's usual if/else condition, but I've thought this small example, which maybe helps you.

I have only EditText and Button as Views:

```
RxTextView.textChanges(editText)
            .map(text -> !TextUtils.isEmpty(text))
            .subscribe(RxView.visibility(button));
```

It'll show the button only if user inputs some text.

Comment: Let's say I have a `LinearLayout` with id 1 who is visible. At the same time, we have another `LinearLayout` with id 2, who is not visible. Now I 'want when in any chance I change the visibility of the id 1 to gone, the id 2 should show up.
It does work with if/else but it means that I need to make a method to call it constantly while doing some work, that's why I wanted to use RxJava.

Comment: It isn't what RxJava about. You should use RxJava for example for working with UI events and actions, not for your own changes in code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better solution if you're using RxBinding library using the RxView's visibility() function:

```
view2.visibility(View.GONE).accept(view1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);
```